# IE7 cleafix not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

I am having issues with IE7 and float clearing on this page:

https://dev.editionpatrickfrey.com/de/books/miss-martin-guggisberg

I am using the Sass pie-clearfix(); mixin and tried all possible other clearfixes without success. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I need a wrapping container to do this. I was just trying to clear floating elements on one level. Adding the container with the Sass pie-clearfix(); mixin solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The ClearFix below may be applied to a Parent of floated children and or as an element below floated elements. This should cover IE6 - IE10.

```
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clear {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

I personally use this ClearFix, but to find out more about this ClearFix, check out this link: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the floatstop to the parent element that contains the floating element:

CSS:

```
.floatstop:after {
 content: ".";
 display :block;
 height :0;
 clear :both;
 visibility :hidden;
}
*:first-child+html .floatstop {min-height: 1px;}/* ie7 fix */
* html .floatstop {height: 1%;}/* ie6 fix */
```

HTML:

```
<div class="floatstop">
 <div>floated div</div>
 <div>floated div</div>
</div>
```